# log full HTTP requests and responses going through a given interface and port

Tags: http, pcap, tshark

I'm looking for a command I can run to watch port 5000 on my local loopback and log the full HTTP requests and responses on it, live, without dumping to a file and postprocessing it.  Desired output would look like:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 23 May 2005 22:38:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Length: 138
Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.3.7 (Unix) (Red-Hat/Linux)
ETag: "3f80f-1b6-3e1cb03b"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close

<html>
<head>
  <title>An Example Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  Hello World, this is a very simple HTML document.
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried using `tshark -i lo0 -d tcp.port==5000,http -Y http` but that doesn't print the full content of the HTTP requests and responses, and it prints a lot of extra stuff I don't care about:

```
   13   2.644627    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    HTTP 387 POST /battsim/loadprofile HTTP/1.1  (application/json)
   21   2.692109    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    HTTP 57 HTTP/1.0 200 OK  (application/json)
   32   2.706703    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    HTTP 100 PUT /battsim/loadprofile/3b3135f0-b8aa-4ece-94c2-e9baf1c4998e/data HTTP/1.1  (text/csv)
   37   2.722450    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    HTTP 244 HTTP/1.0 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR  (text/html)
```

Comment: https://github.com/six-ddc/httpflow

Comment: @SteffenUllrich that looks perfect, I'd be happy to make that the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several tools for this purpose and they are often called something like "httpflow". One example is https://github.com/six-ddc/httpflow  which looks exactly what you want, i.e. just dumping the data.

Answer (score 1):

The `-z follow` option of tshark might be what you're looking for. It takes a stream number and outputs the stream content. For instance, `tshark -r tmp.pcap -z follow,tcp,ascii,1` outputs the content of TCP stream 1 from the capture file `tmp.pcap`.

To retrieve all TCP stream contents in your capture file you could use:

```
for stream in $(tshark -r tmp.pcap -T fields -e tcp.stream | sort -un)
do
  tshark -r tmp.pcap -z follow,tcp,ascii,$stream
done
```

`-z follow` however requires the whole capture file to extract the stream contents. If you want to extract HTTP requests online, you'll need to use something other than tshark.

Comment: it seems like a lot of things in `tshark` can only be accomplished by dumping to a `.pcap` file and then postprocessing it...I was looking for an option that would print to the console as as stuff comes in.

Comment: You'll need a dedicated tool for that (such as the one Steffen Ullrich proposed), tshark is rather meant for per-packet analysis. I haven't compared tools of this kind so I didn't include it in my answer (don't want to be biased toward the only tool I know).

Comment: yeah.  I'm surprised it took me so long to find something that does what I want, I thought people would be debugging HTTP traffic all the time

Comment: I usually debug at the application level, with the logs. It's easier when you have TLS encryption...

Comment: I understand what you mean but I was trying to confirm that a 3rd party lib was sending requests with chunked transfer encoding, and there isn't an easy way to make that lib print its raw http requests, so using an external tool was my best option.